# Roll a fair, six-sided die 10 times. What is the probability that each side appears at least once?

Tags: probability, stirling-numbers

The answer that I got, which is incorrect, is the multinomial coefficient with $n=10$ and $k$ values $(1,1,1,1,1,5)$ multiplied by $6$ divided by the total number of outcomes, $6^{10}$. This in decimal form is equal to $0.003$.

I know the answer is $38045/139968$

Comment: I do not remember the details, but the Stirling numbers (not sure whether of the first or second kind) should help here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can solve this problem using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) by excluding those distributions which are missing one or more of the numbers.

Comment: To emphasize, the Stirling numbers of the second kind are a sort of short-hand for the inclusion-exclusion approach, just with some more flavor and readily available identities.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are more *partitions*, for example $(1,1,1,1,2,4)$ or $(1,1,2,2,2,2)$.

In order to consider all the possible partitions you have to evaluate the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)
$$S(10,6)=22827$$
(see the [table of values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Table_of_values)), that is the number of ways to partition a set of $10$ objects (the number of throws) into $6$ non-empty subsets (the number of values of a die).
Then the required probability is equal to
$$\frac{6!S(10,6)}{6^{10}}=\frac{38045}{139968}.$$